# How to enable CheckJNI through eclipse

Tags: debugging, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I would like to enable CheckJNI for debugging Android JNI.

It can be enable through `adb shell setprop debug.checkjni 1` according to the following page.
http://android-developers.blogspot.tw/2011/07/debugging-android-jni-with-checkjni.html

However, is it possible to enable CheckJNI through IDE - eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Not at present.  The authoritative page is [this one](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#extended_checking).

Comment: The page you provided is the same as the page I described in the question.  That's why I am curious about the capability in IDE settings.

Comment: The page I linked to is part of the developer documentation that is updated with every release.  Any changes will be reflected there.  As of Android 4.3 the feature is still controlled by the system properties.